# Reading from messages properties in spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `messages.properties` file in my spring boot application:

```
mymessage = this message
```

Now, is there a way to get this value from one of my controller methods in spring boot?

Comment: Inject the `MessageSource` and do a `getMessage`.. However why do you need this as this should be done as transparant as possible.

Comment: Actually, what I have is a property that holds a default password value. password = default password.   So anytime I am creating a new user, I supply the default password to the User's getPassword field.

Comment: Then don't put it in the `messages.properties` but `application.properties` and use a `@Value` to inject that property.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what a message.properties file is in relation to spring boot but I know you can have a service.properties file and/or an application.properties file. To read from either of these you can use @Value please see documentation here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

This will allow you to inject your value from your .properties file into your controller